GitLab Deploy Container App to Azure App Service
I have setup a Azure App Service which uses the container publishing model. Everything works as expected but I want to automate deployments with a GitLab pipeline. Therefore, I created a Service Principal and gave it the Contributor role for the App Service. However, in the job logs I can see the following error:
ERROR: (AuthorizationFailed) The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/read' over scope '/subscriptions/yyy/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/foo' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
Code: AuthorizationFailed

This is my pipeline:
deploy:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_SP_ID -p $AZURE_SP_PASSWORD -t $AZURE_TENANT
        - az extension add --name webapp --upgrade
    script:
        - az webapp config container set --name $AZURE_APP_NAME --resource-group $AZURE_APP_RESOURCE_GROUP
          --container-image-name ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

When I assign the Service Principal Contributor role on the subscription level, everything works. But wouldn't that allow the service principal to access all resources under that subscription?

Yes, by assigning the service principal the Contributor role on the subscription level you would give it the access to perform all types of operations towards the resources under the subscription scope.
As the error indicates that it is trying to read the serverfarm resource that is being used by the App Service, my suggestion is that you give the SPN the Reader role on the serverfarm resource and with that avoiding to assign any privileged role on a higher level scope within the management hierarchy.

The issue was that I needed to give reader role on the app service plan. Giving the contributor role on the app service it self is not enough.
